# How to use the Laplace approximation to fit a spatial GLM model

Tags: r, modeling, generalized-linear-model

I would like to fit a spatial generalized linear mixed model, for example, to model spatial count responses by using the Laplace approximation in available statistical software.

I am particularly interested in implementations in R.

Comment: Got some references?

Comment: I mean anyone can present an example to do Laplace approximation in SGLMMs?

Comment: The learning curve will be steep, but you can use AD Model Builder for this -- example here: http://admb-project.org/examples/spatial-models/glmm-with-spatial-structure-described-in-terms-of-covariance-function

Comment: @BenBolker: Has this example an R version so that I can use glmmADMB package?

Comment: No, you can't use glmmADMB for this.  Sorry.  (I'm tempted to ask you to transfer your question to the r-sig-mixed-models list so the answers aren't in two places ...)  If you want to use glmmPQL in MASS you can, but it will be quasi-likelihood rather than the Laplace approximation.

Answer (score 2):

Nested Laplace approximations can be used to fit various spatial models. Papers, tutorials, and lots of examples can be [found here](http://www.r-inla.org/)